# herokuのpostgresqlを使う設定について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsチュートリアルでは、herokuのpostgresqlを使うための設定としては、Gemfileに下記のように追記するだけでした。

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

config/database.ymlは以下のようにデフォルトのままでいじることはありませんでした。

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

database.ymlのproductionの設定のところはsqlite3を使う設定のままになっているのにheroku上ではpostgresqlにちゃんと接続できるのはなぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

仮にこの設定で問題なく動いていたとして、おそらく production 環境(heroku)では sqlite3 で動作していると思います。

個人的には、開発で使うデータベースと、本番で使うデータベースは、同じアダプタを用いるのが良いと思います。

Comment: herokuのDataclips機能でpostgresql上のデータを取得できたので、postgresqlで動いているのは確かなんです。。。